# How do I float a div in the center of the screen

Tags: css

I'm trying to create in HTML5 a view made of `div`'s that displays in the center of the page while the background is grayed out.  Something like the Silverlight child window.  I am having a horrible time trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it with some basic css like so. This is just the css part not javascript to animate it or toggle. But it should be enough to get you started.

**CSS**

```
.div {
    position:absolute;
    top:300px;
    width:300px;
    height:260px;
    left:50%;
    z-index:1000;
    margin-left: -150px; /* negative half the width of the div */
}

.background {
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    position:fixed:
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:999;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="div">
   My Content
</div>
<div class="background "></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is to make the page centered with 900px width, you add this to your `div` element:

```
 width:900px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;
```

for the background, you need to add the following style to you `body` element

```
 color:gray;padding:0px;margin:0px;
```

---

you have to include a width in order to center an element. `margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;` will not work if you did not include a width!